# How can we prove that there is only 1 unique matrix A for a transformation T?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

Denote $T$ is a transformation with domain $\mathbb{R}^n$ and codomain $\mathbb{R}^m$ which can be represented by matrix multiplication $Ax$.
Let $\{e_1, e_2, \dots, e_n\}$ be the standard basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Then $Ax=T(x)$ and columns in $A$ are $T(e_1),T( e_2), \dots, T(e_n)$. In this stage, how can we prove that this is a unique choice?

Comment: Assume by contradiction that two matrices $A \neq B$ represent the same linear transformation $T$. Then $Ax = T(x)$ and $Bx = T(x)$. What are the columns of $A$, and of $B$?

Comment: $Ae_i$ gives the $i$th column of $A$. If $A\ne B$ then $Ae_i\ne Be_i$ for some $i$.

Comment: Any thoughts on these hints, Lucy?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP has lost interest.

Comment: Well I’m still interested